# Geoserver MapFishPrintProvider with rtl text reverse the letters

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish

When sending RTL text to GeoExt.data.MapfishPrintProvider I get the PDF with mirrored text (LTR).

I've added function to reverse the text in the client , but If I add English words inside the RTL text , I will get the english words reversed into RTL...

Is there any solution for this ?

For example :

mapTitle "TEST" will be RTL also...

```
printProvider = Ext.create('GeoExt.data.MapfishPrintProvider', {
                            method: "POST", 
                            timeout : 30*1000,           
                            url: "http://xxxxxxx/geoserver/pdf",
                            capabilities: printCapabilities, 
                            customParams: {
                                mapTitle: reverse("TEST בדיקה"),
                                comment: "בדיקה",
                                dpi:300,
                                outputFilename : "map.pdf"
                            }});
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the software. Suggest that you raise a bug report. For GeoExt, I think the [github tracker](https://github.com/geoext/geoext/issues?page=1&state=open) is the best option, even though the readme points back to the trac instance (and of course, the trac instance points to the github tracker :-)).

I looked at both bug trackers, and don't see anything related to this. You should double check. Bug reports are always helped by test cases, and I'm sure a patch that fixes the problem would be appreciated too.